# clangd cannot parse stl lib header

Tags: c++, g++, clang, clangd

I met a issue when I config my neovim lsp. My lsp client is nvim-lspconfig and clangd is my lsp server.
Here is my clangd setup arguments

```
require('lspconfig')['clangd'].setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  flags = {
    -- This will be the default in neovim 0.7+
    debounce_text_changes = 150,
  },
  capabilities = capabilities,
  cmd = {
    'clangd',
    '--background-index',
    '--query-driver="/app/vbuild/RHEL7-x86_64/clang/latest/bin/clang, \
                     /app/vbuild/RHEL7-x86_64/clang/latest/bin/clang++, \
                     /app/vbuild/RHEL7-x86_64/gcc/latest/bin/gcc, \
                     /app/vbuild/RHEL7-x86_64/gcc/latest/bin/g++"',
    '--clang-tidy',
    '--all-scopes-completion',
    '--cross-file-rename',
    '--completion-style=detailed',
    '--header-insertion-decorators',
    '--header-insertion=iwyu',
    '--pch-storage=memory',
    '--enable-config',
    '--log=verbose'
  },
  filetypes = {"c", "cpp", "objc", "objcpp"}
}
```

And my g++ and clangd version as follow

```
g++ (GCC) 10.3.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

clangd version 14.0.0
Features: linux
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

At the same time, I add the following include path into my CPATH

```
setenv CPATH "/app/vbuild/RHEL7-x86_64/gcc/latest/include/c++/10.3.0:/app/vbuild/RHEL7-x86_64/glibc/2.33/include"
setenv CPATH "/app/vbuild/RHEL7-x86_64/clang/latest/include/clang-c:/app/vbuild/RHEL7-x86_64/clang/latest/include/llvm-c:$CPATH"
```

But I still found these errors in my neovim

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNNsu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEsbv.png)

It seems like clangd cannot find related stl headers. But I checked my include path in $CPATH. It indeed has stl headers. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After check the clangd logs. I think It's the same issue as
https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/1100

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler is g++, clangd needs g++'s driver to find std library. Basically you need to uncomment the queries in cmd table

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure if this is the problem without seeing [clangd logs](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#gathering-logs), but one potential issue is that the argument to `--query-driver` is a **regex** that's matched against the path of the compiler executable from the commands in `compile_commands.json`.

I don't think the comma-separated list of paths you are passing is a valid regex. To match those four executables, you may want to use a more permissive regex like `/app/vbuild/RHEL7-x86_64/*/latest/bin/*`, or otherwise use alternative syntax like `(clang|gcc)` etc.